# How to get variable outside export function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I call const variable in same file but outside export const

```
 export const getData = async ({page="1",limit="10", createdAt="}) => {

    }
```

I want to crate variable like this

```
const params = {
  page = "1",
  limit = "10",
  createdAt="",
}
```

and In export I want to call some thing like this

```
 export const getData = async (params) => {

   }
```

the reason that I want to do like this because I want to make my code more easy to read thanks

Answer (score 0):

By using a self invoking function that return a closure:

```js
const getData = ((params) => {
    return async () =>{
        console.log(params)
    }
})({foo:'bar'})
```